# How to create simple Registration and login using Laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm creating a simple registration form using a tutorial.[LINK](http://blog.cubettech.com/how-to-create-user-registration-form-in-laravel#comment-195) I created everything mentioned there and additionally I added the **Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class** to my **app.php**. But when I run this app in my broswer using this url `http://localhost/ptl/public/register` i get this:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost/ptl/public/register_action" accept-charset="UTF-8"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="roIXm176ZnQyTyYcXjm7Qif7mg2NXdIX0lCZ55z0">
Name :

<input name="name" type="text">

Email :

<input name="email" type="text">

Password :

<input name="password" type="password" value="">

Confirm Password :

<input name="cpassword" type="password" value="">

<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

and my Controller in **app/http/controllers** folder
and my view in resources/views folder
I'm confused about where to create the **model** class and how to use it with the controller and the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check [Official Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#authentication-quickstart) about Authentication and [Laracast free explaining video](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/15)

Sample Routes:

```
// Authentication routes...
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');

// Registration routes...
Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
```

Sample Authentication form view:

```
<!-- resources/views/auth/login.blade.php -->

<form method="POST" action="/auth/login">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}

    <div>
        Email
        <input type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
    </div>

    <div>
        Password
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember Me
    </div>

    <div>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Sample Registration Form view:

```
<!-- resources/views/auth/login.blade.php -->

<form method="POST" action="/auth/login">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}

    <div>
        Email
        <input type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
    </div>

    <div>
        Password
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember Me
    </div>

    <div>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

In the console/terminal write:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

It will automaticly generate routes & views for login,forgotten password and registration

Answer (score 0):

In laravel 5.1 there is a User Model by default. and you can add your models anywhere in app directory(they live  there [See official documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#defining-models)),
You can also use default laravel methods to register/authenticate users [Authentication](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication)

```
// Authentication routes...
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');
// Registration routes...
Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');    
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
```

to your routings. This will route to your auth controllers and use trait for registrating and authenticating users